# Преобразование ссылок вида google.ru

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть выражение, которое преобразовывает ссылки вида http://google.ru. Как дописать, чтобы google.ru распознавало тоже как ссылку?

```
/((ht|f)tp(s)?:\/\/[\w]+[^ \,\"\n\r\t<]*)/is
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(ht|f)tp(s)?:\/\/
```

Заменить на

```
(?:(ht|f)tp(s)?:\/\/)?
```

Comment: @knes, странно тогда работает. Посмотришь в исходный код, а там на пробелы ссылки стоят.

Comment: Видимо, потому, что вторая часть регекспа реагирует практически на любое произвольное слово. Например, на "google", "goo gle", "google ", " google" etc. Пока в голову лезет только один вариант: взять список TLD и проверять, чтобы слово оканчивалось на ".TLD". Но и тут будут глюки, с доменами типа .pl, .py...

Comment: @klopp, как регулярку исправить, чтобы на goo gle не реагировала. Пробелы в ссылках как бы я не видел ещё.

Comment: \s - пробел. добавить его после \n

Comment: Пробелы в ссылках бывают ещё как. Только задача распознавания ссылок без протокола в общем виде вообще не решается, так что смотрите по ситуации, вот тут можно поковыряться: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=url

Comment: @klopp, не нашёл пока там ничего для себя, ибо лень искать дальше. И всё же, если не затруднит, уберите в регулярке преобразование пробелов в ссылку

Comment: Пробел убирается добавлением \s, как написано @knes. Но всё равно реакция будет на произвольные слова без пробела :) Добавим в конец "точка+домен" - вылезут другие побочные эффекты, и так до бесконечности... Поэтому интересен контекст, в котором эти ссылки ищутся.

Comment: @klopp, и что делать? :D

Comment: Зависит от окружения. Вот, например, почему в регекспе есть символ '<'? Это может означать, что ссылки находятся внутри какой-то разметки, и надо смотреть на неё. А если ссылки вводятся куда-то юзерами, то либо обязать их писать протокол, либо выдать специальную кнопочку... Без понимания откуда что берётся можно только гадать.